# admin-ajax.php GET custom-post titles

Tags: custom-post-types, ajax

I can't get the titles of my custom post.

this is what i'm doing:

```
//IN functions.php

function fluid_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('lateral-fluid', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lateral-fluid.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script( 'lateral-fluid', 'ajaxFluid', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}

add_action('init', 'create_post_type');
function create_post_type(){
    resgister_post_type ( 'portfolio',
            array (
                'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('beds'),
                'singular_name' => __('bed')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            )
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_lateral_fluid', 'my_lateral_fluid' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_lateral_fluid', 'my_lateral_fluid' );

function my_lateral_fluid() {
    //echo "test";
    $args = array(   
            "post_type" => "portfolio",
            "posts_per_page" => -1  
    );  
    $portfolio_query = new WP_Query($args);                 

    while($portfolio_query->have_post() ){
        $portfolio_query->the_post();
        echo "<li>" . get_the_title() . "</li>";       
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

I check in my admin-ajax.php url with my action: http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=lateral_fluid, and it didn't display anything. If I uncomment //echo "test"; it display test. I already add 5 custom-post with their titles.

Why I don't get the titles of my custom-post (portfolio). What I'am missing?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** replace:

```
resgister_post_type
```

with:

```
register_post_type
```

to fix the typo.

**Secondly** replace:

```
while( $portfolio_query->have_post() ){
```

with

```
while( $portfolio_query->have_posts() ){
```

where you've forgotten the plural **s**.

### Note

The reason why calling non-existing methods like:

```
$portfolio_query->some_non_existent_method()
```

doesn't raise a PHP error, is the *magic* `__call` method of the `WP_Query` class:

```
/**
 * Make private/protected methods readable for backwards compatibility.
 *
 * @since 4.0.0
 * @access public
 *
 * @param callable $name      Method to call.
 * @param array    $arguments Arguments to pass when calling.
 * @return mixed|false Return value of the callback, false otherwise.
 */
public function __call( $name, $arguments ) {
    if ( in_array( $name, $this->compat_methods ) ) {
            return call_user_func_array( array( $this, $name ), $arguments );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Without it we would get the expected:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   `WP_Query::some_non_existent_method()`

So making typos in `WP_Query` method names can be tricky to detect.

I think it might be better to **throw an exception** instead of returning `false` for *non-compatible* methods:

```
throw new Exception(
    sprintf(
        __( 'Call to undefined method WP_Query::%s' ),
        sanitize_key( $name )
    )
);
```

Comment: I feel really stupid !!!! Thank you very much, I was starting to go crazy!!!

Comment: Don't be, these kind of typos in the method name can be sneaky because they don't  raise PHP errors ;-)  Good IDE might help @PabloLevin

Comment: Yes and I'm new in wordpress. Could you orient me in: How could I get the id and the permalink to use with js? So I can load a custom-post into a <div>

Comment: Check out the [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function @PabloLevin

Comment: I would love to see the exception error message implemented in core, will definitely help a lot with debugging

Comment: yes this is a kind of *stealth bug* that isn't detected by the *error radar* and can challenge the mental state of developers ;-) @PieterGoosen

Comment: Hahahaha yes. It is strange to me that something has never come up like the exception error as we do get posts here from time to time where `have_posts()` and `the_post()` have been spelled wrong. A proper exception error would have saved those poor souls their mental health. Good idea to submit this for future core changes ;-)